# Why is a leading 0 needed in binary literals such as '0b10101000'?

Tags: python

I am confused about the leading `0` in `0b10101000`:

It does not seem  to be a sign symbol.

```
In [1]: bin(168)
Out[1]: '0b10101000'

In [2]: int(bin(168), 2)
Out[2]: 168
```

I assume it should be sufficient, and it would certainly be more succinct, to say `b10101000`.

Why is the leading `0` needed?

Comment: See [What is the rationale for closing "why" questions on language design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170394/what-is-the-rationale-for-closing-why-questions-on-a-language-design) on [meta], referencing https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face". A question asked out of curiosity does not satisfy the "problem that you face" criteria for being on this site.

Comment: ...I think the introductory paragraph in the consensus/accepted answer there applies to this question as well: *I personally think it's a really cool question. It's well written, it explores an area of the language that may not be as well understood as it could be, and it has the potential to give insight into the language. That having been said, it's not a good question for Stack Overflow.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's to not confuse binary literals with variables.

You can express numbers as literals in whatever base (0b -> binary, 0x -> hexadecimal for instance):

```
0b100
>>>4

0x100
>>>256
```

The problem arises when there isn't a leading 0. Python's naming convention for variables is that it must start with an alphabetical character. With the leading 0 the interpreter can tell if it's a literal or a variable.

Answer (score 2):

It would be more succinct, but Python would interpret `b10101000` as a variable name if you used it in code whereas it would interpret `0b10101000` as a binary number.

It would be confusing (to you, the programmer) if Python presented the value to you differently from the way it would expect you to present the value to it in code that you write.